# Linux Nvidia driver works bad for me

Tags: linux, drivers, nvidia-settings

I've installed Bumblebee, it loads nvidia driver correctly... I can see it in `/proc/drivers`:

```
quux@quux-Ideapad-Z570 ~ $ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version 
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  319.60  Wed Sep 25 13:58:16 PDT 2013
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 
quux@quux-Ideapad-Z570 ~ $
```

But driver doesn't work good, I've tried 304, 304-updates and 319-updates:

It gives much lower fps than integrated one. glmark2 benchmark tool rated Nvidia with 59 score and integrated Intel - 751!

When i run `optirun nvidia-settings` it says that `You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run`nvidia-xconfig`as root), and restart the X server.`. Bumblebee config:

```
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false

[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-319-updates
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
#XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
XorgConfFile=/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

As you can see in config I even tried to use xorg.conf generated by `nvidia-xconfig` instead of Bumblebee xorg.conf.nvidia, result is the same.

```
quux@quux-Ideapad-Z570 ~ $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.108  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-07)  Wed Jul 

31 21:27:07 PDT 2013

    Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "Layout0"
        Screen      0  "Screen0"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    EndSection

    Section "Files"
    EndSection

    Section "InputDevice"
        # generated from default
        Identifier     "Mouse0"
        Driver         "mouse"
        Option         "Protocol" "auto"
        Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
        Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
        Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
    EndSection

    Section "InputDevice"
        # generated from default
        Identifier     "Keyboard0"
        Driver         "kbd"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "Monitor0"
        VendorName     "Unknown"
        ModelName      "Unknown"
        HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
        VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
        Option         "DPMS"
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Device0"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen0"
        Device         "Device0"
        Monitor        "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
        EndSubSection
    EndSection
```

And bumblebee config:

```
quux@quux-Ideapad-Z570 ~ $ cat /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia 
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
    BusID "PCI:01:00:0"

#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"

    Option "NoLogo" "false"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

Also `bumblebeed -vv` output

```
quux@quux-Ideapad-Z570 ~ $ sudo bumblebeed -vv
[47743.879935] [DEBUG]Found card: 01:00.0 (discrete)
[47743.879966] [DEBUG]Found card: 00:02.0 (integrated)
[47743.879974] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[47743.880372] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[47743.880387] [DEBUG]Skipping auto-detection, using configured driver 'nvidia'
[47743.880525] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 9493.
[47743.880559] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
[47743.969996] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[47743.970071] [DEBUG]bbswitch has been detected.
[47743.970080] [INFO]Switching method 'bbswitch' is available and will be used.
[47743.970087] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[47743.970093] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[47743.970099] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[47743.970105] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates
[47743.970111] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[47743.970117] [DEBUG] pidfile: /var/run/bumblebeed.pid
[47743.970123] [DEBUG] xorg.conf file: /etc/X11/xorg.conf
[47743.970129] [DEBUG] xorg.conf.d dir: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
[47743.970134] [DEBUG] ModulePath: /usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
[47743.970140] [DEBUG] GID name: bumblebee
[47743.970146] [DEBUG] Power method: auto
[47743.970151] [DEBUG] Stop X on exit: 1
[47743.970157] [DEBUG] Driver: nvidia
[47743.970163] [DEBUG] Driver module: nvidia-319-updates
[47743.970168] [DEBUG] Card shutdown state: 1
[47743.970297] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 9494.
[47743.970330] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
[47743.976076] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[47743.976111] [DEBUG]Configuration test passed.
[47743.976870] [INFO]bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
[47743.977080] [INFO]Switching dedicated card OFF [bbswitch]
[47744.192239] [INFO]Initialization completed - now handling client requests
```

Help me to run nvidia-settings

Comment: Please provide more detail besides "doesn't work good".

Comment: Sounds like vsync is turned on.

Comment: @cybernard I can't run `optirun nvidia-settings` since it says that I am not using nvidia card. I've added xorg.conf and bumblebee.conf above if it makes sence.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked bleeding ages ago, but this works for me: optirun nvidia-settings -c :8

Comment: Further explanation about why this works would make this a much better answer.